# jQuery : Select previous sibling of text node

Tags: javascript, jquery, textnode, siblings

Let's say we have the following HTML code:

```
<div>
    Select Gender:
    <input type="radio" />
    Male
    <input type="radio" />
    Female
</div>
```

My goal is to check the male radio button (the first one). However, I don't know if this radio button will always be the first of the two radio buttons, the only thing for sure is that I want to check the radio button **before** the "male" text.

So this is how I did:

```
$('div') 
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return (((this.textContent || this.innerText || $(this).text() || '').search(new RegExp(labels[i], "ig")) >= 0) && (this.nodeType === 3)); 
    })   
    .prev('input[type=radio]')
    .attr('checked', 'checked');
```

But this doesn't work. A quick debug show that the text node is correctly selected, but then the .prev() function returns nothing. I've also tried with previousSibling but no better results.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you add some `class` and `id` attributes to your markup? It will look great and provide semantic meaning!

Comment: Any chance of being able to change the markup to make those text nodes into properly bound `<label>` tags?

Comment: @DavidSouther: which version of jQuery are you using ? I tried on jsFiddle too but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Mathletics: no, because actually it's a bookmarklet that will be run on other websites, not on mine.

Comment: You could prefix your ids and classes with some unique identifier for your bookmarklet to avoid collisions, just like every single jQuery plugin does.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you mean putting ids in the input tags ? Yes, but the problem remains the same: how do I know which id to put in each input tag?

Comment: If you are trying to automate the radio selection for yourself, then know that most forms will not have that structure..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes of course, and my script tests many kinds of forms (those with labels, with/without tables etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the radio button before the "male" text.

http://jsfiddle.net/hmariod/ZtuKD/1/

```
function setM() {
    var inps = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0; i < inps.length; i++){
        if(inps[i].type == "radio" ){
            if(inps[i].nextSibling.data.indexOf("Male") > -1){
                inps[i].setAttribute("checked","checked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Should have thought of this idea. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
     var tn = this.textContent || this.innerText;
     return $.trim(tn) === 'Male';
}).prev('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FdHAa/

Or:

```
<div>
    Select Gender:
    <input id='male' type="radio" />
    <label for='male'>Male</label>
    <input id='female' type="radio" />
    <label for='female'>Female</label>
</div>
```

```
$('div label').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'Male';
}).prev().prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Yes, i know, but actually i'm trying to make a bookmarklet, so this piece of code will be running on other websites (not on mine), and unfortunately programmers don't all put labels next to inputs...

Comment: Well, yes it does, but i really need the regex part.